# Disable past dates in date_combo

Tags: forms, datetime

Is there a way to disable the past dates in the date pop-up while using the date combo form api? Specifically, I have a date type field in a content type, on which I want to do this.

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Use hook_date_combo_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context).

I have used it in commerce discount module: while adding discount.

Example :

```
  $current_path = current_path();
  if ($current_path == "admin/commerce/store/discounts/add") {
   $element["value"]['#datepicker_options'] = array(
     'minDate' => 0,
   );
   $element["value2"]['#datepicker_options'] = array(
    'minDate' => 0,
   );    
  }
```